# How to create a list by searching if a column contains a value?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have in column A values (red, white) and in column B values (Marie, Jane, David, Jack etc.) There are several hundreds of rows so that there are different names once but for each name a color (red or white) is assigned. So for example:

column A column B

red Marie

red Jane

white David

red Jack

white Ashley

etc.

I want to search all names with color white and make a list of names to column C.

I know IF-statement is simplest solution BUT I don't want blank cells inbetween. I want a full list of names so that there are no useless cells. So =IF(A1="white"; B1; "") would not work because I don't want the "" part. Instead, is it possible to move to next cell to see if that cell/row includes the word white? And if so, it would return the value next to the cell "white".

I have also tried INDEX-MATCH but it only returns the first value to when I try to use autofill. So the name Marie would just copy hundred times.

VLookup hasn't helped me either.

Comment: Can you modify columns A and B? Sorting or filtering on column A seems like the easiest answer.

Comment: Just use a filter

Comment: No, I can't modify columns A and B. And filtering would be easiest but column's B data will be changed often and the point is to "automate" the process so that when the data is changed, column C will automatically change too. Otherwise the user would need to filter and then copy the values to column C.

Answer (score 0):

I used a Table structure so that the formulas would autofill if the table changed in size.

```
C2: =IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[[#All],[Name]],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/([Color]=Table1[[#Headers],[White]])*ROW(Table1)-ROW(Table1[#Headers])+1,ROWS($1:1))),""))
```

[image]

- Return an array of the Table row numbers that match the condition. The non-matched will return `FALSE` or `0`

`([Color]=Table1[[#Headers],[White]])*ROW(Table1)-ROW(Table1[#Headers])+1`

- `1/(…)` will change that to an array of row numbers, or a `DIV/0` errors
- The `AGGREGATE` function then returns the relevant row numbers.
- the `IFERROR` function returns a blank if there is no relevant row number
- If you change the column header `White` to `Red`, the names that appear will change.